# Passing ifstream as an argument to Class Constructor

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to pass:   ifstream infile;

in my main (), to the constructor of a class called "FIFO":   FIFO (infile);

In the header file of FIFO (FIFO.h), I have:

```
FIFO (std::ifstream);
std::ifstream infile;
```

And in FIFO.cc, I have:

```
FIFO::FIFO (std::ifstream & INFILE)
{
         infile = INFILE;
}
```

I kept getting like (There are more of them, I just paste one of them):

In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/localefwd.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/string:45,
                 from FIFO.cc:7:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ios_base.h: In member function ‘std::basic_ios >& std::basic_ios >::operator=(const std::basic_ios >&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ios_base.h:793: error: ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:47: error: within this context

I am not sure if passing ifstream using reference works or not, or it is my codes problem.

Thanks!

Comment: It's best and common practice to avoid all-uppercase identifiers like FIFO and INFILE unless they're preprocessor macros... just helps avoid clashes and contain the "evils" of macros (see Marshall's C++ FAQ Lite if you're unaware of the issues).

Answer (score 13):

In your constructors declaration you are taking the `std::ifstream` by value instead of by reference. Instead of

```
FIFO (std::ifstream);
```

it should be

```
FIFO (std::ifstream&);
```

and you are storing the member variable 'infile' by value instead of by reference.

```
std::ifstream infile;
```

should be

```
std::ifstream& infile;
```

Since you are now storing a reference to the ifstream you need to initialize it in the *initializer list* instead of assigning it in the constructor.

```
FIFO::FIFO (std::ifstream & INFILE)
    : infile(INFILE)
{
}
```

This is because the copy constructor of `std::ifstream` is private (or deleted in C++11). By storing the member variable by value you are attempting to make a copy of the `std::ifstream` object passed to the constructor.

Comment: I changed my code according to your advices, but the errors are still there. Any other things I may be missing? Thanks!

Comment: as an aside, I typically have my classes and functions accept istreams instead of ifstreams. Then you can still pass them the fstream version, but if you want to pass cin for testing purposes or something, you can. Either way, both need to be passed by reference as Captain Oblivious said.

Comment: @user2297481 It's hard to say without actually seeing the code and the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures of your prototype declaration and implementation do not match. Change

```
FIFO (std::ifstream);
```

to

```
FIFO (std::ifstream &);
```