# passing a file to constructor to read

Tags: c++, file, constructor

```
class Read
{
public:
    Read(ifstream &file)
    {
        mFile=file;
    }
private:
    ifstream mFile;
    string str;
};


int main()
{
    Read r("sample.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use the constructor to read a file. I saw another example on stack overflow and tried to replicate it but failed. How do i properly read a file using a constructor.
Is the syntax way off?

Comment: For one thing: `"sample.txt"` is not an `ifstream`.  Need to create one of those somewhere, then use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096109/passing-ifstream-as-an-argument-to-class-constructor This was the example I found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy or assign `ifstreams`, but you can initialize them from a string literal. So you could do this:

```
class Read
{
public:
    Read(const char* filename) : mFile(filename) {}
private:
    ifstream mFile;
    string str;
};
```

Note that this would make `Read` non-copyable and non-assignable. But move construction and move assignment would work.

Note that, if you really want to pass an `ifstream`, then the best you can do is pass a temporary, and use the data member's move constructor. You can achieve it with this constructor:

```
Read(ifstream&& file) : mFile(std::move(file)) {}
```

Usage:

```
Read r1("file.txt");                // const char* ctor
Read r2(std::ifstream("file2.txt"); // ifstream&& ctor
```

Answer (score 1):

"Sample.txt" isn't an ifstream. Instead, open the file with the passed string.

> mFile.open(file);
>   Where file is a c string.

Answer (score 0):

Standard file streams cannot be copied. The assignment in the constructor is invoking the stream's private (`delete`'d in C++11) copy-assignment operator. The correct way do this would be to invoke the appropriate constructor with the *member initializer-list*. The parameter should be of type `std::string` as well.

```
Read(const std::string& file)
   : mFile(file)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{ }
```